# reading a textfile from r.raw on android

Tags: android, file, filereader

I've got a json file in R.raw.test123,

I need to process that with GSON.

Step one is; read the text into a string, I want to do that using;

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

The FileReader expects a string as filename, but how do I turn R.raw.test123 into a string which I can pass to the FileReader.

I've googled for about 4 hours on this, still can't find it. And I know its probally a noob question, but I'm new to droid programming, I come from a .net background, so this is all very new to me...

Thanks,

Dennis

Answer (score 3):

As answered by **hooked82** you can use get the `inputstream` with:

```
InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test123);
```

and then using method to convert it into string:

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append((line + "\n"));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("LOG", e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("LOG", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

So you can get the string with `convertStreamToString(stream);`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the trouble answering this, my original problem is allready fixed. Still for my own learing my original question is still open; The FileReader expects a string as filename, but how do I turn R.raw.test123 into a string which I can pass to the FileReader.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

How about doing the following:

```
InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test123);
```

Comment: I've solved it using the InputStream yes, but still something easy like passing the name to the FileReader how is that done? (Thanks btw Hooked82)