# File not found issue in Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I need to access `myfile.txt` file using `FileReader` in Android , please suggest me where to add the text file in Eclipse. I tried it adding it in Resource and Asset but I am getting File not found issue.

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("myfile.txt");
```

Even

```
File ff = new File("myfile.txt");
```

File Supports only the below listed parameters

[image]

FileReader Supports only the below listed parameters

[image]

Note: I want solution for this issue , only with FileReader or File

Comment: also a possible duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953378/reading-a-textfile-from-r-raw-on-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory would be `/res/raw/` this is where you put all your extra resources. 
you can refer to it using  `getResources().openRawResource(resourceName)`
and check here [Android how to get access to raw resources that i put in res folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856407/android-how-to-get-access-to-raw-resources-that-i-put-in-res-folder)

EDIT:

[how can i edit the text files in assets folder in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845227/how-can-i-edit-the-text-files-in-assets-folder-in-android)
in short
the easiest way would be to copy the file to external directory then do your stuff there 
link is here
[Android: How to create a directory on the SD Card and copy files from /res/raw to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851712/android-how-to-create-a-directory-on-the-sd-card-and-copy-files-from-res-raw-t)

One thing to mention  - prior to 2.3 the file size in the assets cannot exceed 1MB.

---

hope it helps abit

Comment: but FileReader or File don't accept InputStream as parameter, getResources().openRawResource(resourceName) returns InputStream

Comment: i will update my answer in few minutes. this one is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I obtain my file from the SD card, perhaps this can be some use to you.

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        File options = new File(getAppDirectory(), "portal.xml");
}
```

The getAppDirectory method used in the bit of code looks like this :

```
private String getAppDirectory() {
    return new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() 
            + "/foldername/foldername/");
}
```

After this bit of code I also make sure the file exists and what not before I attempt to read from it.

Comment: What u have in getAppDirectory() method?

Comment: Updated my answer, sorry about that ;)

Comment: Thanks, But I want to have it in the app bundle, and wanted to use it when my application is launched

Comment: Then I'd advise you do look into the `AssetManager` class and place your document in the `/assets` in your Android project.